# Como alterar um valor em outra classe?

Tags: java, android

Estou querendo alterar o valor de uma variável em outra classe mas não estou conseguindo.

```
package com.cursoandroid.firebaseapp.novotestebanco;

public  class Logado {

   public String situacao;


    Logado(String situacao){
        this.situacao = "deslogado";
    }

    public  String getSituacao() {
        return situacao;
    }

    public void setSituacao(String situacao) {
        this.situacao = situacao;
    }
}




botaoMostrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Logado logado = new Logado("");
            logado.setSituacao("logado");
            mostrar.setText(logado.getSituacao());
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Mostrar.class));



        }
    });
```

> Classe *Mostrar*

```
public class Mostrar extends AppCompatActivity {
    public TextView text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mostrar);

        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.texto);

        Logado logado = new Logado("");
        text.setText(logado.getSituacao());
    }
}
```

Comment: Pode dar mais detalhes? Qual a variável que você deseja alterar? O que acontece quando você tenta executar seu programa? Apresenta algum erro? Assim ficará mais fácil do pessoal te responder.

Comment: Note que no construtor `Logado(String situacao)` o parâmetro situacao é inútil já que você inicializa o atributo com um valor fixo `this.situacao = "deslogado"`.

Comment: coloquei a variavel como static e deu certo, vlw mesmo pessoal pela ajuda.